# Modify href between jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

i need some help with these

I have header.jsp, login.jps and register.jsp.

I build my Body with Header.jsp and another JPS. 
I want to change my 'Help' link of Header.jsp depending on the Jsp i build. How i can do that?

I looked for javascript solution but is a 'dirty' solucion and Sonar is saying 'God DONT DO THAT'.

More details to explain mysefl, my Header.jsp has that code:

```
<ul class="pull-right">
            <c:if test="${empty sessionScope.USER}">
                <li><a href="#" class="help"><spring:message code="header.manual"/><span><spring:message code="header.help"/></span></a></li>
            </c:if>
```

If i build with Login.jsp i want that href linked to  "url.com/home.public?help_login"  and if is Register.jsp i want href liked to "url.com/home.public?help_register".

INFO: when i use register.jsp my url is  "url.com/register.public" otherwise i use login.jsp my url is "url.com/login.public".

Sorry if my english is bad, but i think you will understand it.

EDIT: Layout.jsp

```
<body class="home" onload="nobackbutton();">  
    <c:choose>     
        <c:when  test="${not empty sessionScope.ADMIN}">
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="headerAdmin" />
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="menuAdmin" />
        </c:when >
        <c:otherwise>
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />   
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>        
    <div class="container-fluid">
          <tiles:insertAttribute name="miga" />
          <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: checkout https://tiles.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

Finally i used a document.ready (javascript) to identify de href and modify it and make sonar ignore that because i found nothing better than these. I don't want lose more time ...

Thnk Hooch for help

Answer (score -1):

Can't you simply do something like the following?

```
    <%
        if (${sessionScope.USER} != null) {
    %>
            <li><a href="#" class="help"><spring:message code="header.manual"/><span><spring:message code="header.help"/></span></a></li>
    <%
        }else{
    %>
            <li><a href="#" class="help"><spring:message code="header.manual"/><span><spring:message code="header.help"/></span></a></li>
    <%
        }
    %>
```

Edit: since you need to know the current page you could check

```
<%= request.getServletPath() %>
```

In the header.jsp

Comment: Off course you need to change the href in if else branches.

Comment: I have something like that but im using the else clausule to test if the user has session, if he has it means he logged in and the Home help is no longer usefull. My problem is to identify if he is at login or at register form.  Im thinking to use 'modelAndView.addObject()' and then test if he is at register or login action but i need to think a bit more about it

Comment: "<%= request.getServletPath() %>" i already tried it and it does not work because it returns me layout.jsp (my 'main' jsp witch i use to build the page)

Comment: Can you share a skeleton of your layout.jsp?

Comment: I eddited the question